# Splitting a pandas DataFrame of email 'From' field into sender's name, email address

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've a `pandas` `Dataframe` consisting of a single column which is the extraction from the **From** field of emails e.g.

```
                                                   From
0          Grey Caulfu <grey.caulfu@ymail.com>
1                   Deren Torculas <deren.e.torcs87@gmail.com>
2            Charlto Youna <youna.charlto4@yahoo.com>
```

I want to take advantage of the `str` accessor to **split the data into two columns**, such that the first column is, *Name*, contains the actual name (first name last name), and the second column, *Email*, contains the email address).

If I use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.From.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),
                                   columns = ['Name','Email'])
```

This is *almost* what I need, but it puts the surname in the Email column (i.e. it places the last two items from  `split()` into this column). How do I modify this so that `split()` knows to stop after the first space when populating the first column?

Once we achieve this, we then need to make it a little more robust, so that it can handle names that contain three elements e.g.

```
Billy R. Valentine <brvalentine@abc2mail.com>
Yurimov | Globosales <yurimov@globosaleseu.com>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`rsplit()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) instead of [`split()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) , to split from the reverse. Example -

```
In [12]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.From.str.rsplit(' ',1).tolist(), columns=['Name','Email'])

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
             Name                        Email
0     Grey Caulfu      <grey.caulfu@ymail.com>
1  Deren Torculas  <deren.e.torcs87@gmail.com>
2   Charlto Youna   <youna.charlto4@yahoo.com>
```

Comment: As usual Anand, you've provided an elegant, intuitive solution. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `expand=True` and create new columns from the str without having to create a new df:

```
In [353]:
df[['Name','e-mail']] = df['From'].str.rsplit(' ',1, expand=True)
df

Out[353]:
                                         From            Name  \
0         Grey Caulfu <grey.caulfu@ymail.com>     Grey Caulfu   
1  Deren Torculas <deren.e.torcs87@gmail.com>  Deren Torculas   
2    Charlto Youna <youna.charlto4@yahoo.com>   Charlto Youna   

                        e-mail  
0      <grey.caulfu@ymail.com>  
1  <deren.e.torcs87@gmail.com>  
2   <youna.charlto4@yahoo.com>
```